# Check if a query in stored procedure was successful or not

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to see if a query within a stored procedure was successful or not?
For example, I want to know if the following query was successful:

```
if (UPDATE CurrentState SET buyer = bid
                    WHERE ID = company_id_var
                    AND buyer < bid;)
then
    //Variable was updated, do something
else
    //Variable was not updated, do something else
end if
```

I`m trying to avoid to use a SELECT-query to check if it has been set to the the new value.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ROW_COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) function to see if anything got updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can `do something` with [an on-update trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html).